# How can we add a dashboard to lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dashboard

I have below requirement to customize the home page of users to show different dashboard based on their ROLE.
I had used below code in Visualforce. Code for the same is as below:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="true">
<script>              
  var sw = "{!$UserRole.Name}"
  if(sw == "Admin" || sw == "JP Tech"){
    location.href = "https://login.salesforce.com//01Z4xxxxxxxx?isdtp=vw"; }
  else if (sw =="JP  Global" || sw =="JP Global Onsites") {
    location.href = "https://login.salesforce.com//01Z4xxxxxxxxxx?isdtp=vw";   }
  else if (sw =="JP EU" || sw =="JP BD" || sw =="JP CEM" || sw =="JP Onsites") {                    
    location.href = "https://login.salesforce.com//01Z4xxxxxxxxx?isdtp=vw"; }                
  else if (sw =="JP APAC" || sw =="JP APAC Onsites") {
    location.href = "https://login.salesforce.com//01Z4xxxxxxxxxxx?isdtp=vw"; }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

How can I implement the same in Lightning. Is there a way to import a dashboard in a lightning component.

Comment: You can create different home pages with dashboards embedded in it for different profiles.

Comment: I need to display dashboard based on ROLE and not based on profile.